# Youtube API array sorting with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, get, youtube-api

I'm having some trouble sorting the results in this code. The results order is just random every time... How can i fix this?

And I want to make a function for the repeating GET code with an array of the channel ID's. Who can help me please? It's much appreciated.

```js
var ItemArray = [];

var d1 = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCVQ2Z9dNQ2aJJ10f6SgBH0g&type=video&order=date&maxResults=1&part=snippet&KEY",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
idee = item.id.videoId;
tittie = item.snippet.title;
cattit = item.snippet.channelTitle;
datie = item.snippet.publishedAt;
ItemArray.push([datie, cattit, idee, tittie]);
            });
        });

var d2 = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UC2xskkQVFEpLcGFnNSLQY0A&type=video&order=date&maxResults=1&part=snippet&KEY",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
idee = item.id.videoId;
tittie = item.snippet.title;
cattit = item.snippet.channelTitle;
datie = item.snippet.publishedAt;
ItemArray.push([datie, cattit, idee, tittie]);
            });
        });

var d3 = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCGHi_s4RrqUh4hsS4mLbiPg&type=video&order=date&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key=KEY",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
idee = item.id.videoId;
tittie = item.snippet.title;
cattit = item.snippet.channelTitle;
datie = item.snippet.publishedAt;
ItemArray.push([datie, cattit, idee, tittie]);
            });
        });

var d4 = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCy5QKpDQC-H3z82Bw6EVFfg&type=video&order=date&maxResults=1&part=snippet&key=KEY",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
idee = item.id.videoId;
tittie = item.snippet.title;
cattit = item.snippet.channelTitle;
datie = item.snippet.publishedAt;
ItemArray.push([datie, cattit, idee, tittie]);
            });
        });
$.when(d1, d2, d3, d4).done(function() {

ItemArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
});

for(i=0;i<=ItemArray.length;i++){
$('#mytable').append('<tr><td>'+ItemArray[i][0]+'</td><td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/'+ItemArray[i][1]+'">'+ItemArray[i][1]+'</a></td><td><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ItemArray[i][2]+'">'+ItemArray[i][3]+'</a></td></tr>');
}
})
})
```

Comment: I think the problem lies in your sorting function. Depending on how you get the date from youtube, you may need to convert it, as Array.prototype.sort requires you to return a positive or negative number. For example have you tried doing something like `datie = new Date(item.snippet.publishedAt)` and comparing like `return a[0].getTime() - b[0].getTime()`?

Comment: yes youre right. its working now thanks :)

I have another question. I want to put channeld's in an array so i only need 1 get function. How I do that? And what should i write after then "when"... thanks..

Comment: I don't think you can put multiple channeIIds in a search call (at least I hadn't found anything in the YouTube API docs).

Comment: I have transformed my comment into an answer. If it has helped, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Accoding to the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) documentation, `publishedAt` is being returned specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

As [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) requires you to return a positive/negative number, I would compare the number of milliseconds, i.e. store your date like

`datie = new Date(item.snippet.publishedAt)`

and comparing it in your sort-function as

`return a[0].getTime() - b[0].getTime()`